# trying to install windows hotfix, but getting a negative exit code

Tags: windows, windows-8, exit-code, hotfix

I am trying to install windows-8-RT kb2771744 hotfix.  I am getting a negative exit code:
-2125124329

I converted that into hex: 7FDBFFE9

I looked around, I am not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Possibly related: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/58610812-c0c6-4f35-8394-cdb5ee9a2c30/i-am-unable-to-install-the-kb2771744-package-from-within-kb2770917?forum=w8itproinstall

Comment: upload the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS

Comment: How have you converted it to hex?

Comment: If I convert 7FDBFFE9 then I get 2145124329 but not -2145124329

Answer (score 1):

It means "this update is not applicable to your system", possibly because you are trying to install an update for Windows 8 RT (ARM) on an Intel system.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938205 for all Windows Update error codes.

```
0x80240017 WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE Operation was not performed because there are no applicable updates.
```

By the way, to make sense of a Windows error code that displays as a negative number you have to interpret is as an unsigned 32-bit number. You can do this easily in the Windows calculator:

- Select "Programmer" mode
- Select "Dword" format
- Enter the negative number
- Change to "Hex" display